# Can I get SSL private key and certificate if using Heroku ACM?

Tags: ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate, private-key

I am using Heroku ACM (Automated Certificate Management). Somehow I found myself in the situation of needing the SSL key and certificate.

Can I get the key and certificate from Heroku?

Comment: "Somehow I found myself in the situation of needing the SSL key and certificate"—can you tell us more about this? I don't think you can get the private key, but depending on why you need it there might be a better answer.

Comment: so, to add: Heroku ACM uses Letsencrypt in the background. This means the certificates are only valid for 3 months (if I remember correctly), and are automatically rotated by Heroku.